# No api call in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I have come to know that api calls should always be handled in services and not done in directive. Can somebody throw some light on it? What are pros and cons if I make api call from directive?

Comment: It has to do with the architecture of the system. While the directive could be considered a presentation layer, a service usually serves as a data/logic layer. This approach simplifies development, testing and maintenance.

Comment: AngularJS is an MV* framework. Directives create view from the model and  communicate user events to the controller. The controller uses services to to do API calls and update the model. Putting API calls in directives bypasses the model and violates the MVC discipline.

Comment: Seems legit, thanks for explationation